# AS3 playing/communicating with external swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

ok so im bringing in a test external swf like so:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();                     
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("load2.swf"); 
loader.load(url);                                    
addChild(loader);
```

Now im trying to envoke a goto and play like so:

```
var loaded:Object;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaded);

function handleLoaded(e:Event):void {
  loaded = e.target.content;
}

load1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);

function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  if (loaded) {
    loaded.gotoAndPlay("outro");
  }

  //other content here.
}
```

this simple external test swf has 10 frames. @ frame 1 theres a "intro" label, @ frame 5 theres a "stop" action, and on frame 6, theres an "outro" label.

problem is that, when i click the button, it reloads the external swf and plays from frame 1.

any ideas/tips/hints etc id gladly appreciate.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `loaded` as a MovieClip:

```
MovieClip(loaded).gotoAndPlay("outro");
```

**Ok, so that didn't fix it...**

Without seeing more of the application it's hard to say more, because the code provided works fine on it's own.  If this code is on a timeline, it might be worth putting a trace in alongside the load operation to see if the parent playhead is replaying.

**A ha**

I believe I've solved it.  The issue is coming from the presence of the TLF text in load2.swf.  I proved this by creating my own version of load2 without any TLF text, and this worked fine with your eerase.fla.  When I added a TLF textfield to my load2, it started to show the behaviour you're experiencing.  So the fix is simply to not use TLF textfields in any loaded SWF.  I have tested using classic textfields with no issue.

The reason this occurs is because TLF textfields require to load data, and so it creates an artificial preloader that loads in your content.  When you issue a gotoAndPlay action, you are in fact talking to this preloader, not the timeline you created, and the consequence is that the preloader 'loads' another copy of your content.  This is not an actual HTTP request as the content is all inside load2.swf, hence nothing appearing in Firebug's Net panel.  You can see more clearly what is being created by decompiling one of your SWF's.

Comment: hello Shanethehat. i tried and the same thing. it loads but it REimports the swf and plays from 1.

Comment: I built a test using only the code you've provided here and it plays without issue, so I think there must be something else going on.  What is `load1`?

Comment: hello again, thanks for taking the time. whats above in code,  is exactly what i have on my swf. this test swf has literally nothing in it. a one frame parent swf, and the swf to be imported (load2.swf). matter of fact, heres the problem, ive uploaded so you can see. http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/test.html

Comment: I'm having trouble looking into that SWF. Can you describe what `load1` is?

Comment: load1 is a button on the stage. or rather its instance name

Comment: It shouldn't re-import the SWF on your button press.  It could potentially play from frame 1, if it can't find the "outro" label, but there's no code in there that would cause the SWF to be re-loaded.  Have you verified via Firebug (or some other HTTP monitoring utility) that the SWF is actually being re-loaded with a new URLRequest?

Comment: hello meddlingwithfire. i say its being somehow reloaded because, if you look at this link http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/test.html when you press that button, the animations plays again and the text in the background gets darker (one ontop of the other) and the button stops working (like its being loaded ontop of the other) ver weird. also @ shanethehat, i tried the Event:INIT and the same thing happens. very weird. again thanks for the help and time guys. appreciate the looks on it.

Comment: There isn't a 2nd load showing up in Firebug.  When the `load1` button is clicked it seems to become inactive, which suggests something being placed on top of it. I'm out of ideas, unless you can post the source files somewhere.

Comment: ok Shanethehat, heres the same link as before, i updated it real fast with a download here to the actual.fla -- link is on top of the page. (ontop of the flash). let me know and again Thanks. woops, forgot the link lol http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/test.html

Comment: matter of fact, heres a direct link. http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/eerase.fla

Comment: @somdow - On my mobile at the moment. I'll look at the file later, but you could try changing your textfields from TLF to classic text.

Comment: sup Shane. ill do so asap but the button is an invisible box. not the text.

Comment: thanks to all for the looking into this matter. im sure yall are wondering what the problem is aswell. ive included the .fla in this link http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/eerase.fla

Comment: could you also provide the fla  for the 2nd file?

Comment: AHAHAHAA NICE! GOD SOMETHING SO SIMPLE!!! i wouldve NEVER thought of that!!!! omg wao. im blown away. been a few days now LOL. THANK YOU! VERY MUCH appreciated! you dont know!

Answer (score 1):

Try listening for Event.INIT instead of Event.COMPLETE.

Quoting the documentation for LoaderInfo:

> complete: Dispatched when data has loaded successfully.
>
> init: Dispatched when the properties and methods of a loaded SWF file
>   are accessible and ready for use.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html

**Edit**: I see now that you don't call gotoAndPlay directly on load, but later. I'll leave the answer here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just checking the wrong function in your if statement inside the handleClick function. You should be testing for if(handleLoaded) rather than if(loaded)...

```
//these 4 lines load ext swf
var loader:Loader = new Loader();// create a new instance of the Loader class
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("load2.swf");// in this case both SWFs are in the same folder 
loader.load(url);
// load the SWF file;
addChild(loader);
//////////
//test below
var loaded:MovieClip;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaded);

function handleLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
    loaded = e.target.content;
    }

load1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);

function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
    if (handleLoaded)
        {
            loaded.gotoAndPlay("outro");
        }

    //load new swf
    }
```

Comment: This is just checking if the function is defined. `if(loaded)` checks that the loaded variable has an assigned value, in other words that the load has completed.

Comment: yes i agree, but hey im getting nowhere so i tried it anyways lol and it doesnt work. i tried it anyways and i get this error with what you have above : "Warning: 3553: Function value used where type Boolean was expected.  Possibly the parentheses () are missing after this function reference." im starting to give up lol. i guess my next quesiton is, how would YOU guys write it? i dont mind redoing it, cause this just aint working.

Answer (score 0):

i improve it

```
function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
    if (handleLoaded)
        {
            loaded.gotoAndPlay("outro");
        }

    //load new swf
    }
```

replace to :

```
function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (handleLoaded(e))
    {
        loaded.gotoAndPlay("outro");
    }

    //load new swf
}
```

It works sure.. I am testing on Flex SDK 3.6a .. But i haven't test on Flash CS3/CS4/CS5 yet. Thanks